# Laravel 5.6 - fat Model, skinny Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Trying to understand fat Model, skinny Controller principle of Laravel development on a very basic example.

---

**1st example** I want to retrieve all Posts. In PostController I could write:

```
public function index() {
    $posts = Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
    return view('home', compact('posts') );
}
```

And get all the posts.

---

**2nd example**: In Post model:

```
public function readAllPosts() {
    return $this->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
}
```

PostController:

```
public function index() {
    $post = new Post;
    return view('home', [
        'posts' = > $post->readAllPosts()
    ]);
}
```

---

Is it correct and what's really a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve directly from the model without instantiating the class by making the function static. For example, you're returning an ordered collection of posts.

Post model:

```
public static function getOrdered() {
    return Post::get()->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
}
```

PostController:

```
public function index() {
    return view('home', [
        'posts' = > Post::getOrdered()
    ]);
}
```

The idea behind this is you're separating concerns between the database logic and the controller logic.